# How do I write a function that accepts a string and will return a total number of certain characters in the string, without using .count?

Tags: python, string, list, function

beginner here. Trying to figure out how I can define a function that counts the total number of occurrences of certain characters in a string. Say, we want to count the number of occurrences of the letters a and b. I need to do it within a for loop. What I have so far is this. Please let me know what I can do to make this work!

```
#define functions 
def ch_count(word):
  total=0
  for letter in word:
    if letter==L1:
      total=total+1
  return total
#main program
L1=["a","e","y"]
print(ch_count("Merry Christmas")
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. "I want this" is not an appropriate post for this forum. Once you've gotten started on writing the code yourself and encounter a specific problem you need help with, feel free to come back.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you added some attitude to this post that wasn't warranted. In no part of my post did I say, "I want". It was a hypothetical statement in which someone wanted to accomplish something. I have been trying to figure out my issue for several days trying to write my own code, none of which has worked, so as a last resort I asked on this forum. I wasn't aware there was a comment police service on this forum. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a default dictionary. Unlike a normal dictionary, it provides a default value is a key does not exist in a dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

string = 'quick brown fox'

letter_count = defaultdict(int)

for letter in string:
  letter_count[letter] += 1

print(letter_count)
```

Comment: You can do this with standard `dict` as well. `letter_count = {};for letter in string: letter_count[letter] = letter_count.get(letter, 0) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum`:

```
string = 'Some test string'
c = 'a'
sum(x == c for x in string)
```

Checking for multiple characters instead:

```
c = 'abc'
sum(x in c for x in string)
```

Or you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to find the count of each character:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(string)
counts[letter]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could write a function which takes 2 arguments. The string to check, and the letter that we want to use to count occurrencies in the string.

```
# I will use a as a default letter
def count_occurrencies(s, letter='a'):
    return sum([i == letter for i in s])
```